# Hardware access through JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Can we access the hardware service routine using JavaScript?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do?

Comment: It is possible to access hardware details in javascript. http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/JavaScript/How-to-Use-JavaScript-for-Hardware-Knowledge/

Comment: actually that is ActiveX. You can only access hw if there is an exploitable bug in the browser.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With the JavaScript inside your browser, No.

However JavaScript can also be used on the server-side, as they guys at [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) are doing (just to take one example). In this case, you would have access to server-side resources and I/O, using JavaScript as a scripting language.

Answer (score 2):

one more important thing : Javascript access to the browser is limited

I dont think so its possible via javascript because according to me its client side scripting language. But i thin with serverside scripting you can access hardware of server machine(not sure with this)

read more about this : http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=137449

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in mobile app development you may find PhoneGap interesting. It's free at the moment and it allows to develop html5 css javascript apps in a mobile multiplatform wrapper that provide javascript access to hardware features like gps, compass, accelerometer, storage...etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you need access to the entire file system on the client, watch folders for changes, start applications, encrypt or sign documents, connect to USB devices, etc. please have a look at JSFS.

It allows secure and unlimited access from your web page to computer resources on the client without using a browser plugin technology like AcitveX or Java Applet. However, a peace of software has to be installed too.

In order to work with JSFS you should have basic knowledge in Java and Java EE development (Servlets).

Please find JSFS here: https://github.com/jsfsproject/jsfs. It's free and licensed under GPL.